# convert this select/join query to delete matching records

Tags: mysql

How do I convert the following query to delete the records that match ProjectID/Project_ID to 14?

```
select * from Project join Project_Assigned 
where Project.Project_ID = Project_Assigned.ProjectID 
and Project.Project_ID = 14;
```

The select statement works but when I try to convert it to instead delete the matching records I get ERROR 1064 (42000).

```
delete * from Project join Project_Assigned 
where Project.Project_ID = Project_Assigned.ProjectID 
and Project.Project_ID = 14;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DELETE FROM Project
WHERE Project_ID = 14
  AND Project_ID IN
    (SELECT ProjectID FROM Project_Assigned
     WHERE ProjectID = 14)
```

Comment: Now I get this error: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`fyp_db`.`Project_Assigned`, CONSTRAINT `ProjectID` FOREIGN KEY (`ProjectID`) REFERENCES `Project` (`Project_ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Comment: Project_Assigned has field ProjectID, so the subquery should be with ProjectID instead of Project_ID.

Answer (score 0):

You got the first error because delete cannot contain a join clause.

I don't think you can do it in only one query. You need to consider all the related tables with Project_Assigned and Project and look at their foreign keys and delete their records first.
In addition, you must delete the records from Project_Assigned before you delete the records from Projects, because of the foreign key.